How to properly get API json records in php
Am working with an API with the code below. When I echo the output of the API call as per this line of code echo $output = curl_exec($ch); I got the following result below.
data: {"choices":[{"delta":{"content":"","role":"assistant"},"finish_reason":null,"index":0,"logprobs":null}],"created":1731684833,"id":"ccb3d64e-2319-464a-86d5-7255e3a2c552","model":"Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct","object":"chat.completion.chunk","system_fingerprint":"fastcoe"} data: {"choices":[{"delta":{"content":"Hello. How can I assist ","role":"assistant"},"finish_reason":null,"index":0,"logprobs":null}],"created":1731684833,"id":"ccb3d64e-2319-464a-86d5-7255e3a2c552","model":"Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct","object":"chat.completion.chunk","system_fingerprint":"fastcoe"} data: {"choices":[{"delta":{"content":"you today?","role":"assistant"},"finish_reason":null,"index":0,"logprobs":null}],"created":1731684833,"id":"ccb3d64e-2319-464a-86d5-7255e3a2c552","model":"Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct","object":"chat.completion.chunk","system_fingerprint":"fastcoe"} data: {"choices":[{"delta":{"content":"hey","role":"assistant"},"finish_reason":null,"index":0,"logprobs":null}],"created":1731684833,"id":"ccb3d64e-2319-464a-86d5-7255e3a2c552","model":"Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct","object":"chat.completion.chunk","system_fingerprint":"fastcoe"} data: {"choices":[{"delta":{"content":"are you there"},"finish_reason":"stop","index":0,"logprobs":null}],"created":1731684833,"id":"ccb3d64e-2319-464a-86d5-7255e3a2c552","model":"Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct","object":"chat.completion.chunk","system_fingerprint":"fastcoe"} data: [DONE]

Now I tried to print the value of the content in the foreach() loop as per the line of code below but nothing is being displayed.
foreach($json['data']['choices'] as $rec){
echo $content = $rec['delta']['content'];
}

Please How do I get all the values for content
Here is the full code
$url ="https://api.sambanova.ai/v1/chat/completions";
$payload ='{
    "stream": true,
    "model": "Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct",
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a helpful assistant"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "hello"
        }
    ]
    }' ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer $sambanova_api_keys" , 'Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
echo $output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($json['data']['choices'] as $rec){
echo $content = $rec['delta']['content'];
} 


What debugging have you done? Have you got PHP error reporting enabled, even? If $output contains literally the text you've shown is in your post, that isn't valid JSON, so json_decode will fail to parse it and return null. That should then result in errors when you try to loop through the non-existent decoded data - demo: https://3v4l.org/gLZso

P.S. As an aside, naming a variable $json when it's the result of a json_decode operation is a bit nonsensical. json_decode takes a JSON string as input. The output from json_decode is usually an PHP object or array - i.e. something which is not JSON anymore. If you give your variables meaningless or misleading names it can make your code a lot harder to understand and thus more difficult to diagnose and debug issues.

Anyway, it looks like the API is actually sending you a series of separate, individual JSON objects, with other content in between. That isn't parseable as a single JSON string (hence the errors in your code). As per https://docs.sambanova.ai/sambastudio/latest/open-ai-api.html I think you need to set "stream": false in the options you send to the API, so it'll give you a single JSON object (containing all the data) as the response instead. Then you should be able to decode it easily.
